# How do I get the total number of records in a fixture from a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, javascript-framework

I'd like to get the total number of records in my fixture from my controller.  Here is my fixture code:

FIXTURE

```
App.Items.FIXTURES = [
 {
    id: 1
 },
 {
    id: 2
 },
 {
    id: 3,
 }
];
```

In this case, there are 3 total records in the fixture. How do I get that total in my controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using something like this:

```
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return this.store.find('items');
  } 
});
```

The `store.find` returns a [Ember.PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html) instance, so you can observe the `isFulfilled` property to know when the data is loaded:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    doSomethingWithTotal: function() {        
        var length = this.get('model.length');
        // do something with de length
    }.observes('model.isFulfilled')
});
```

Like this sample http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/UeCWV/

Comment: I need to access the length of the fixture in my controller though. How do I access it there?

Comment: Sorry now I see, I am updating it :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this though, and now when I navigate to a page in my app, it simply doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask ArrayController for the property `content` and it will return an array, which gives you access to `length`.

Here's an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYSjD/

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  doSomethingWithTotal: function() {
    return this.get('content.length')
  }.property('content')
});
```

The way this works is that `App.ItemsRoute`.`model` returns a Promise to find items, and when that completes, another method of `ItemsRoute` is called: `setupController`.

Ember will automatically handle `setupController` for you, which populates a controller with the returned model data. The `content` property of `ItemsController` will be set, giving your property `doSomethingWithTotal` a real value.

Comment: What if my controller is using ObjectController? Doesn't seem to work then.

Comment: An ObjectController only contains a single object, not an array of objects.